# Delete vertices with the same position in a one geometry in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Here I have a simple node tree which result has vertices with identical location. There are 8 point and 2 pairs of them are at the same spot I need remove them. I tried to do so with my transfer and capture attribute nodes according to position node

[image: Problem]

Comment: I have no idea what you actually want to do here, and judging from your comment on the existing answer, your question also seems to be worded a bit fuzzy, but you could replace the node `Split Edges` with `Convex Hull`. Another possibility would be to select the vertices to be deleted by index or by their position.

Comment: You are talking facts, but that is not what I will be able to do if a have several of these

Comment: Then please be so kind and describe a little more precisely what you actually want to do here, because I honestly don't quite understand it either, which is why I wouldn't write an answer here yet.

Comment: I have a castle, it is  ready and works well, but there is an issue that I just can't figure out: castle has peaks at the top, they are distributed using vertices on edges, the problem is I can't delete that middle edge which creates unnecessary peaks which I want to delete. Since the castle is procedural it can be having any shape normal castle would have.
If I want to delete these I need to have an access to every pair of edges that have the same position and then delete them using position node somehow.
I separated edges on purpose to implement this idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of what you will do with that, so it may not work for your case, but it seems to be working fine to me.

[image]

This node tree will delete all points that share the same exact location, like the ones produced by the *Split Edges* node:

[image]

You can also change the domain of the nodes to *Edge* to delete edges in the same position:

[image]

### $$\text{Explanation}$$

When transferring data from the nearest, when there's elements in the same position, the nearest element will be the same despite the existence of two or more elements equally distant. <sub>(Not sure if that happens in all cases)</sub>

We can use this behaviour to identify elements that share the same position if we transfer the index using the same geometry as target:

Here the highlighted elements share the same position:

[image]

We can see that the transferred index is the same for the elements in the same position. These are the elements that should be deleted, but for that a selection of all elements that have a repeated transferred index is needed.

To get the selection we first accumulate $1$ using the transferred index as *Group Index*, then we check if the total accumulated is greater than $1$, if it is, then the element share the position with another element.

Comment: That totally works, it is exactly what I wanted except I actually wanted to delete edges, but that's my mistake, thank you so much

Comment: Has anyone a node setup doing the same in 4.0 nodes, since the transfer attribute node doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score -1):

Does the merge by distance node work for you?

[image]